# How to use window.screenLeft in IE11, with sub-frame and zoom

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

`window.screenLeft` returns correct values, whatever zooming you are using, if you are in a "main frame".

By correct values, I mean that multiplying them by `window.devicePixelRatio`, you successfully get the X offset, in screen pixels, of the view rendering your document, relative to the device screen.

When you are in a sub frame (using the `<iframe>` tag), all is fine when Zoom is 100%.

However, when you are in a sub frame, with Zoom not at 100%, the returned values do not make sense, afaict.

Example, OK (sub-frame, Zoom 100%)
[image]

Example, KO (sub-frame, Zoom 150%)
[image]

Source 1: Main Frame:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO</title>
    </head>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Text in the Main Frame
            </td>
            <td>
                <iframe width=600 height=450 name="SomeFrame" src="src2.html"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Source 2: Sub Frame

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO (frame)</title>
        <script>
            function DoTheCalc() {

                document.getElementById( "W_L" ).value = window.screenLeft;
                document.getElementById( "W_T" ).value = window.screenTop;

                document.getElementById( "P_R" ).value = window.devicePixelRatio;

                document.getElementById( "W_X" ).value = window.screenLeft * window.devicePixelRatio;
                document.getElementById( "W_Y" ).value = window.screenTop * window.devicePixelRatio;

                return;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor='green'>
        <input type="button" id="CALC_BUT" value="Compute" onclick="DoTheCalc();"/>
        <br/>
        <label>
            screenLeft
            <input id="W_L"/>
        </label><br/>
        <label>
            screenTop
            <input id="W_T"/>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
             Pixel Ratio 
            <input id="P_R"/>
        </label><br/>
        <label>
             Left, Zoom adjusted 
            <input id="W_X"/>
        </label><br/>
        <label>
             Top, Zoom adjusted
            <input id="W_Y"/>
        </label>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: MSIE browsers default with a zoom transform origin down the center of the top window... other browsers transform from the top left. Center your table (with css, not the depreciated align attribute) in the top window. To test reduce the zoom level... MSIE browsers will transform down the center line.... other browsers will transform from the top left.

Comment: @RobParsons Ok, but what about my question? What does represent `window.screenLeft` for a zoomed sub-frame?